# Symfony - files of var\sessions\dev are empty

Tags: symfony

I'm developing a Symfony 3.4 site locally using Wamp64, PHP 7.2.14 and FosUser to manage my users.

When I connect with some users in the dev environment, the files create in var\sessions\dev are empty and that makes mistakes of type :

*session_start(): Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed*

I don't have a problem in the prod environment, the files of var\sessions\prod is full

config.yml

```
framework:
    #esi: ~
    translator:
        fallbacks: ['%locale%']
    secret: '%secret%'
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    trusted_hosts: ~
    session:
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
```

config_dev.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing_dev.yml'
        strict_requirements: true
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'
            level: debug
            channels: ['!event']
        console:
            type: console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ['!event', '!doctrine', '!console']
        # To follow logs in real time, execute the following command:
        # `bin/console server:log -vv`
        server_log:
            type: server_log
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            host: 127.0.0.1:9911
```

Thank you for any help !

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `gc_probability` to your session settings:

```
session:
    gc_probability: ~
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
    handler_id: session.handler.native_file
    save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
```

**Or** try to make your PHP session directory writable.

Comment: ```gc_probability: ~``` don't work, I'm looking for how to make your PHP session directory writable

Comment: I changed ```session: save_path: ~``` to use ```session.save_path ="c:/wamp64/tmp"``` of php.ini but I have same result :/